# Haskell API for manipulating Tree/Forest

Tags: haskell, tree, api

I'm experimenting how a Relation (a cartesian product's subset) can be implemented in Haskell using different data classes.

Forest and Tree allow to keeps together in a single data structure different relations each one of different n-arity.

This set of functions require only the Eq constraint and a simple Normal Form. (The two show functions require the additional Show constraint.)

The examples allow to quick test the functions.

```
module RelationT
    (isTreeInNormalForm
    ,isForestInNormalForm
    ,toTreeNormalForm
    ,toForestNormalForm
    ,equTrees
    ,equForests
    ,unionOfTwoTrees
    ,unionOfTwoForests
    ,unionOfForests
    ,addTreeToTree
    ,addForestToTree
    ,addForestToForest
    ,addTreeToForest
    ,appendTreeToTree
    ,appendForestToTree
    ,appendForestToForest
    ,growthTree
    ,growthForest
    ,fmapLeafsOfTree
    ,fmapLeafsOfForest
    ,showF
    ,showT) where

import Data.Tree
import Data.List

-- -------------------- CAVEAT --------------------

-- Forests and subforests must be in NORMAL FORM.
-- (Node values of th same level must all be different.)

-- ============================== NORMAL FORM ==============================

-- Each tree and forest must result True.

isTreeInNormalForm :: Eq a => Tree a -> Bool
isTreeInNormalForm (Node _ subforest) = isForestInNormalForm subforest

isForestInNormalForm :: Eq a => Forest a -> Bool
isForestInNormalForm [] = True
isForestInNormalForm [Node _ subfrst] = isForestInNormalForm subfrst
isForestInNormalForm (Node x _ : ndxs) =
    let (oks,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == x) ndxs
    in case oks of
      [] -> isForestInNormalForm others
      _   -> False

-- "Fusion" of the nodes in the same level that have the same value 

toTreeNormalForm :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a 
toTreeNormalForm (Node x subforest) = Node x $ toForestNormalForm subforest

toForestNormalForm :: Eq a => Forest a -> Forest a
toForestNormalForm [] = []
toForestNormalForm [Node x subfrst] = [Node x (toForestNormalForm subfrst)]
toForestNormalForm (Node x subfrst : ndxs) = 
    let (oks,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == x) ndxs
    in if null oks
       then Node x (toForestNormalForm subfrst) : toForestNormalForm others
       else Node x (unionOfForests $ map (\(Node _ subf) -> subf) oks) : toForestNormalForm others

-- ============================== EQUIVALENCE ==============================

-- Forests and subforests are CONSIDERED equivalent if differs only by the order of nodes in the same level.

equTrees :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
equTrees (Node x subfrstX) (Node y subfrstY)
  | x == y = equForests subfrstX subfrstY
  | otherwise = False

equForests :: Eq a => Forest a -> Forest a -> Bool 
equForests [] [] = True
equForests [] _ = False
equForests _ [] = False
equForests (Node x subfrstX : ndxs) ndys =
    let (oks,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == x) ndys
    in case oks of
      []  -> False
      [Node _ subfrstZ] -> equForests subfrstX subfrstZ && equForests ndxs others
      _   -> error "NOT in Normal Form"

-- ============================== COMBINE ==============================

unionOfTwoTrees :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> [Tree a]
unionOfTwoTrees nd (Node _ []) = [nd]
unionOfTwoTrees (Node _ []) nd = [nd]
unionOfTwoTrees ndx@(Node x subforestX) ndy@(Node y subforesty)
  | x == y = [Node x (unionOfTwoForests subforestX subforesty)]
  | otherwise = [ndx, ndy]

unionOfTwoForests :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
unionOfTwoForests [] frst = frst
unionOfTwoForests frst [] = frst
unionOfTwoForests  (ndy@(Node y subfrstY) : ndys) ndxs = 
    let (oks,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == y) ndxs
    in case oks of
      []  -> ndy : unionOfTwoForests ndys others
      [Node z subfrstZ] -> Node z (unionOfTwoForests subfrstY subfrstZ) :  unionOfTwoForests ndys others
      _   -> error "NOT in Normal Form"

unionOfForests :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => t [Tree a] -> [Tree a]      
unionOfForests frsts = foldr unionOfTwoForests [] frsts

-- -------------------- Addition --------------------

-- Addition is non-commutative.
-- The first tree is "added" to the second only if the "root" values are the same.
-- The following functions behaves similarly.

addTreeToTree :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
addTreeToTree (Node _ []) nd = nd
addTreeToTree (Node y subfrstY) ndx@(Node x [])
  | y == x = Node x subfrstY
  | otherwise = ndx
addTreeToTree (Node y subfrstY) ndx@(Node x subfrstX)
  | y == x = Node x $ addForestToForest subfrstY subfrstX
  | otherwise = ndx

addTreeToForest :: Eq a => Tree a -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
addTreeToForest (Node _ []) frst = frst
addTreeToForest _ [] = []
addTreeToForest ndy@(Node y _) frst =
    let (oks,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == y) frst
    in case oks of
      []  -> frst
      [ndz] -> addTreeToTree ndz ndy : others
      _   -> error "The forest is NOT in Normal Form"

addForestToTree :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> Tree a -> Tree a
addForestToTree [] nd = nd
addForestToTree ndys nd@(Node x subforestX) = 
    case filter (\(Node w _) -> w == x) ndys of
      [] -> nd
      [Node _ subfrstZ] -> Node x $ appendForestToForest subfrstZ subforestX
      _   -> error "The forest is NOT in Normal Form"

addForestToForest :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
addForestToForest [] frst = frst
addForestToForest _ [] = []  -- !!!
addForestToForest (Node y subfrstY : ndys) ndxs = 
    let (oks,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == y) ndxs
    in case oks of
      []  -> addForestToForest ndys ndxs
      [Node z subfrstZ] -> Node z (unionOfTwoForests subfrstY subfrstZ) :  addForestToForest ndys others
      _   -> error "The second forest is NOT in Normal Form"

-- -------------------- Append --------------------

-- Thees functions appends trees or forests to the leaves of the target forest.
-- For each target leaf the condition is that the value of the leaf have to be equal to the value of the "root" of what would be appended.

appendTreeToTree :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
appendTreeToTree (Node _ []) nd = nd
appendTreeToTree (Node y subfrstY) ndx@(Node x [])
  | y == x = Node x subfrstY
  | otherwise = ndx
appendTreeToTree ndy (Node x subfrstX) = Node x $ map (\nd -> appendTreeToTree ndy nd) subfrstX

appendForestToTree :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> Tree a -> Tree a 
appendForestToTree [] nd = nd
appendForestToTree frst ndx@(Node x []) =
    case filter (\(Node y _) -> y == x) frst of
        []  -> ndx
        [Node _ subforest] -> Node x subforest
        _ -> error "The forest is NOT in Normal Form"     
appendForestToTree frst (Node x subforestX) = Node x $ appendForestToForest frst subforestX

appendForestToForest :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]      
appendForestToForest [] frst = frst
appendForestToForest frst [] = frst
appendForestToForest frstY  frstX = map (\ndx -> appendForestToTree frstY ndx) frstX

-- ============================== CONSTRUCTION ==============================

-- These functions can selectively add nodes to the leaves of the target.

growthTree :: (t -> Forest t) -> Tree t -> Tree t
growthTree f (Node x []) = Node x (f x)
growthTree f (Node x subfrst) = Node x $ growthForest f subfrst

growthForest :: (t -> Forest t) -> [Tree t] -> [Tree t]
growthForest f [] = []
growthForest f frst = map (growthTree f) frst

-- ============================== LEAF'S VALUE MODIFICATION ==============================

-- Thees functions nodify only the leaves of the target.

fmapLeafsOfTree :: (a -> a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
fmapLeafsOfTree f (Node x []) = Node (f x) []
fmapLeafsOfTree f (Node x subfrst) = Node x $ fmapLeafsOfForest f subfrst

fmapLeafsOfForest :: (a -> a) -> Forest a -> Forest a
fmapLeafsOfForest f [] =  []
fmapLeafsOfForest f frst = map (fmapLeafsOfTree f) frst

-- ============================== PRETTY PRINT ==============================

-- Functions that are useful for values other than strings.

showF :: Show a => [Tree a] -> IO ()
showF = putStr . drawForest . map (fmap show)

showT :: Show a => Tree a -> IO ()
showT = putStr . drawTree . fmap show

-- ============================== EXAMPLES ==============================

tr1 = Node "John" [Node "friends" [Node "John" [], Node "Sally"[]]
                   ,Node "cars" [Node "Laputa" [], Node "Pinto"[]]
                   ,Node "motorbikes" [Node "Thunderbird"[]]]

tr2 = Node "Mary" [Node "motorbikes" [Node"Varadero" []]
                  ,Node "past holidays" [Node "Rome" [],Node "Sydney" []]]

tr3 = Node "John" [Node "motorbikes" [Node"Vespa" []]
                  ,Node "past holidays" [Node "Rome" [],Node "Paris" []]]

tr4 = Node "John" [Node "friends" [Node "Mary" [], Node "Rick"[]]
                  ,Node "past holidays" [Node "Rome" [], Node "London" []]]

tr5 = Node "Frank" [Node "home" [Node "New York" []]]

tr6 = Node "Sally" [Node "phone numbers" [Node "345-25-33" [], Node "898-38-234" []]]

tr7 = Node "Rose"  [Node "phone numbers" [Node "525-33-425" []]]

tr8 = Node "Thunderbird" [Node "manufacturing company" [Node "Triumph Engineering"[]]]

tr9 = Node "Varadero" [Node "manufacturing company" [Node "Honda" []]]

fr1 = [tr1, tr2]

fr2 = [tr4, tr5]

fr3 = [tr6, tr7]

fr4 = [tr8,tr9]

-------------------------

ex1 = showF $ unionOfTwoForests fr1 fr2
ex2 = showF $ unionOfTwoForests fr1 fr2
ex3 = showF $ unionOfForests [fr1,fr2,fr3,fr4]

ex4 = showF $ addForestToForest fr2 fr1
ex5 = showF $ addForestToForest fr1 fr2

ex6 = showF $ appendForestToForest fr4 fr1
ex7 = showF $ appendForestToForest fr3 fr1

ex10 = showF $ appendForestToForest (unionOfForests [fr3,fr4]) (unionOfForests [fr1,fr2])
ex11 = showF $ appendForestToForest (unionOfForests [fr3,fr4]) (unionOfForests [fr1,fr2,fr3,fr4])

countryOf x = case x of
    "Rome"  -> [Node "country" [Node "Italy" []]]
    "Paris" -> [Node "country" [Node "France" []]]
    _       -> []

ex20 = showT $ growthTree countryOf tr3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might need some more testing.  The function `isForestInNormalForm` is wrong, since it thinks the following forest is in normal form:

```
badfr1 = [Node "x" [Node "y" [], Node "y" []], Node "z" []]
```

and the function `toForestNormalForm` is wrong since if you apply it to:

```
badfr2 = [Node "x" [Node "y" [], Node "y" []], Node "x" [], Node "z" []]
```

you get a normalized forest with no `"y"` nodes.

In general, a recursive function on a list structure that handles the singleton case specially:

```
foo [] = ...
foo [x] = ...
foo (x:xs) = ...
```

increases the change of making an error.  In both of these broken functions, you are mishandling `x` in the `(x:xs)` case (forgetting to recurse in `isForestInFormalForm`, and forgetting it entirely in the `else` branch of your `toForestNormalForm`).

For `isForestInNormalForm`, you should be able to drop the singleton case entirely and move its check into the general recursive case:

```
isForestInNormalForm :: Eq a => Forest a -> Bool
isForestInNormalForm [] = True
isForestInNormalForm (Node x f : ndxs) =
    let (dups,others) = partition  (\(Node w _) -> w == x) ndxs
    in case dups of
      [] -> isForestInNormalForm f && isForestInNormalForm others
      _   -> False
```

However, `partition` isn't really necessary here.  You just want to know if there are any duplicates.  If there aren't then `ndxs` and `others` are equal anyway, so you don't need `partition` to create `others`.  This gives an even clearer version:

```
isForestInNormalForm :: Eq a => Forest a -> Bool
isForestInNormalForm [] = True
isForestInNormalForm (Node x f : ndxs) =
  if any (\(Node w _) -> w == x) ndxs
  then False
  else isForestInNormalForm f && isForestInNormalForm ndxs
```

or simplified to:

```
isForestInNormalForm :: Eq a => Forest a -> Bool
isForestInNormalForm [] = True
isForestInNormalForm (Node x f : ndxs) =
  all (\(Node w _) -> w /= x) ndxs && isForestInNormalForm f && isForestInNormalForm ndxs
```

But I favor writing a version that more directly implements the definition:  a forest is in normal form if there are no duplicates in its top-most labels and all of the subtrees is in normal form.  (At least, I *think* that's the definition you intend.)  You can do this by first checking for duplicates and then recursively making sure the subtrees are in normal form:

```
isForestInNormalForm' :: Eq a => Forest a -> Bool
isForestInNormalForm' ts
  = noDuplicates (map rootLabel ts) && all isTreeInNormalForm ts
```

You can write a `noDuplicates` that requires only `Eq` using `nub`:

```
noDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
noDuplicates xs = nub xs == xs
```